# Split string into substrings of given length with remainder

Tags: r, string, substring, split

Given a string such as:

```
text <- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I would like to chop the string into substrings, for example length 10, and keep the remainder:

```
"abcdefghij"
"klmnopqrst"
"uvwxyz"
```

All the methods I know for creating substrings will not give me the remainder substring with 6 characters. I have tried answers from previous similar questions such as:

```
> substring(text, seq(1, nchar(text), 10), seq(10, nchar(text), 10))
[1] "abcdefghij" "klmnopqrst" ""
```

Any advice as to how to obtain all the substrings of the desired length and any remainder strings would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vectors that you use for the `first` and `last` arguments in `substring` can exceed the number of characters in the string without error/warning/problems.  So you can do

```
text <- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

sq <- seq.int(to = nchar(text), by = 10)
substring(text, sq, sq + 9)
# [1] "abcdefghij" "klmnopqrst" "uvwxyz"
```

Comment: Thank you - this does the job. As you point out, my error was that the sequence terminated if it tried to extend beyond the string length.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
strsplit(text, '(?<=.{10})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "abcdefghij" "klmnopqrst" "uvwxyz"
```

Or you can use the `library(stringi)` for faster approach

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(text, '.{1,10}')[[1]]
#[1] "abcdefghij" "klmnopqrst" "uvwxyz"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice; this approach also works perfectly for me. Am I right in surmising this is using perl regexps to find: strings where the condition (ie: any character) is met less than or equal to 10 times?

Comment: It is using the perl lookbehind `(?<=.{10})` which asserts that what immediately precedes the current position of string is any ten characters `.{10}`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using `strapplyc` involving a fairly simple regular expression.  It works because `.{1,10}` always matches the longest string that is no longer than 10 characters:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(text, ".{1,10}", simplify = c)
```

giving:

```
[1] "abcdefghij" "klmnopqrst" "uvwxyz"
```

**Visualization** This regular expression is simple enough that it does not really require a visualization but here is one anyways:

```
.{1,10}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Gew4efUG1JVQ5F9n)